# Need Help - List index out of range

Tags: python

```
x = int (raw_input('Introduceti Ziua in care doriti adaugarea: '))
print
print "     Options Available"
print "---------------------------------"
print "1  -- FOOD"
print "2  -- BOOKS"
print "3  -- SPORTS"
print "4  -- Clothing"
print "5  -- Transport"
y = int (raw_input('Introduceti tipul dorit: '))
m = int (raw_input('Introduceti valoarea dorita: '))
a[x][y]=a[x][y] + m
```

This is inside one of my functions. `a` is global and is defined as a matrix with all values set to 0, for example `a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]`.  If I try `a[1][2] = a[1][2] + m` I see the error message `List index out of range`.

Please help.

Comment: This is not causing this issue, what value you provided for m??

Comment: @DevC: `m`'s value is irrelevant. The only thing a rogue `m` value could cause would be a `TypeError`.

Comment: Try putting a print str(a) right before your last line.  Then copy and paste the console text into your question, including the input, output and error.

Answer (score 4):

Can't reproduce this here:

```
>>> a = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
>>> a[1][2] = a[1][2] + 999
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 999, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You are aware that `[1]` accesses the *second* element of a list?

If you want to create an array of `x` lists with `y` zeroes each, do

```
a = [[0] * y for _ in xrange(x)]
```

For example:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> y = 5
>>> a = [[0] * y for _ in xrange(x)]
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

- `[0] * y` creates a list of `y` zeroes.
- This is is done inside a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `x` times.

You may ask yourself: Why not simply do `a = [[0] * y] * x`? Go on, try it and see what happens. It works, doesn't it? Now do `a[0][0] = 1` and see what happens then...

Comment: a is build as global in main as stated above. I am inputting for x values in between 1,31 and for y 1,5. a actually looks like this in my main.  a = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

Comment: @MuresanIonut: More to the point, please show how you're building `a`, and what you're inputting for `x` and `y`.

Comment: if you input anything greater than 1 for x you will be out of range. x can be 0 or 1 only as a has 2 elements only.

Comment: I must have mistaken rows of columns. What's the easiest way to create a matrices with a rows and b columns for example? Also thank you for your answer

Comment: Ty Questions answered